# why my activity stopped on device

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I make an application which is working fine on the emulator but when I execute it on mobile device it crashed. The issue is in Intent. For Example the code is :

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Bubble");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String b = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivities.this, ""+ b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (b.equals("Bubble")) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bubble.class);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent1); }
```

The Toast is working fine in mobile. But when I place intent It stopped executing

Comment: provide the crash log

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getApplicationContext()`. Just use your `Activity`'s `Context` at the place of `getApplicationContext()` and if you are starting an `Activity` from an `Activity` then just call `startActivity(intent)` alone, no need o call through `Context`

```
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add("Bubble");
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String b = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(SearchActivities.this, ""+ b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (b.equals("Bubble")) {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(SearchActivities.this, Bubble.class);
                        startActivity(intent1); 
                    }
            }
```